# OpenGL total beginner and 2D animation project?

Tags: c, opengl, animation, 2d

I have installed GLUT and Visual Studio 2010 and found some tutorials on OpenGL basics (www.opengl-tutorial.org) and 2D graphics programming. I have advanced knowledge in C but no expirience with graphics programming...

For project (astronomy - time scales) , i must create one object in center of window and make other 5 objects (circles,dots...) to rotate around centered object with respect to some equations (i can implement them and solve). Equations is for calculating coordinates of that 5 objects and all of equations have **parameter t** (as time). For creating animation i will **vary parameter t from 0 to 2pi with some step** and get coordinates in different moments. If task was to print new coordinates of objects it would be easy to me but problem is how to make animation of graphics. Can i use some functions of OpenGL for rotation/translation ? **How to make an object to move to desired location with coordinates determined by equation?** Or i can redraw object in new coordinates every millisecond? First thing i thought was to draw all objects, calculate new coordinates, clear screen and draw all objects in new coordinates and repeat that infinitely..(it would be primitive but will work?)

Here is screen shot of that objects - http://i.snag.gy/ht7tG.jpg . My question is how to make animation by calculating new coordinates of objects each step and moving them to new location. Can i do that with basics in OpenGL and good knowledge of C and geometry? Any ideas from what to start? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or i can redraw object in new coordinates every millisecond? First
>   thing i thought was to draw all objects, calculate new coordinates,
>   clear screen and draw all objects in new coordinates and repeat that
>   infinitely..

This is indeed the way to go. I would further suggest that you don't bother with shaders and vertex buffers as is the OpenGL 3/4 way. What would be easiest is called "immediate mode", deprecated by OpenGL 3/4 but available in 1/2/3. It's easy:

```
glPushMatrix(); //save modelview matrix
  glTranslatef(obj->x, obj->y, obj->z); //move origin to object center
  glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES); //start drawing triangles
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); //a nice red one
    glVertex3f(0.0, +0.6f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-0.4f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(+0.4f, 0.0f, 0.0f); //almost equilateral
  glEnd();
glPopMatrix(); //restore modelview matrix/origin
```

Do look into helper libraries `glu` (useful for setting up the camera / the projection matrix) and `glut` (should make it very easy to set up a window and basic controls and drawing).

It would probably take you longer to set it up (display a rotating triangle) than to figure out how to use it. In fact, here's [some code to help you get started](https://gist.github.com/4600974). Your first challenge could be to set up a 2D orthogonal projection matrix that projects along the Z-axis, so you can use the 2D functions (`glVertex2`).

Answer (score 0):

> First thing i thought was to draw all objects, calculate new coordinates, clear screen and draw all objects in new coordinates and repeat that infinitely..(it would be primitive but will work?)

That's exactly how it works. With GLUT, you set a display function that gets called when GLUT thinks it's time to draw a new frame. In this function, clear the screen, draw the objects and flush it to the screen. Then just instruct GLUT to draw another frame, and you're animating!

Might want to keep track of the time inbetween frames so you can animate things smoothly, but I'm sure you can figure that part out.

OpenGL is really just a drawing library. It doesn't do animation, that's up to you to implement. Clear/draw/flush is the commonly used approach for it though.

*Note: with 'flush' I mean `glFlush()`, although GLUT in multi-buffer mode requires `glutSwapBuffers()`*

Comment: Thanks. And one more question.. how to set up coordinate system of my animation? Is that simple? When i want to create circle with center, for example (6,8), how it will be represented on screen? Is that done by translate function, translating from (0,0)?

Comment: Either update the matrices so screen coordinates are GL coordinates, or transform your own coordinates into the standard OpenGL matrix of 2x2 (-1.0f to 1.0f on the X and Y axis)

Answer (score 0):

The red book explains the proper way to draw models that can first be translated, rotated, scaled and so on: http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter03.html

Basically, you load the identity, perform transforms/rotations/scales (which one you want first matters - again the book explains it), draw the model as though it was at the origin at normal scale and it'll be placed in its new position. Then you can load identity and proceed with the next one. Every frame of an animation, you glClear() and recalculate/redraw everything. (It sounds expensive, but there's usually not much you can cache between draws).